# Need to send a confirmation e-mail with cancellation link using Java

Tags: jms, google-calendar-api

*This question is based on the booking an event in google calendar...*

The user will fill out a details form and submit. A confirmation e-mail should be sent that includes a link to modify the booking.

How can this be achieved?

**Details:** The application runs in **Groovy-grails** and makes **java** calls for adding, updating, retrieving events in google calendar. **Google Calendar API v3** is integrated with existing application for recording events.

Answer (score 0):

*Your question is generic so this is the best I can offer...*

**Getting started:**

Google provides decent documentation on working with the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).

**Sending Emails:**

You could use Google Developers: [JavaMail](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail) to send the email... or [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push)

**Calendar Events:**

I suggest you look at the [Calendar Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) to understand how you might handle updates...

*Enjoy...*